# Hiding async/await pattern from callee

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I have a javascript module to expose an API. I want to change the implementation to add asynchronous calls, that I had not before. The exposed API should not change

So now, some functions of the API should call some external webservices in an asynchronous way. I'm using the `async/await` pattern to call those webservices and wait for the result, avoiding the callback hell.

Unfortunatelly, I understand that I have to expose those functions as async and the other functions are standard non async.

I'd like to hide this to my callees so that they are not responsible to deal with the await or promise. reasons:

- They already have some code using my API which are not calling the webservice, therefore are not returning promises. When I change the body of my functions to be async, I don't want them to change their code  to add await in front of some API functions
- It is my business to know some asynchronous calls are made.
- Async/await is complex to understand to my users, I don't want my users to bother with it

Is there a solution for that? Do you have a pattern that wraps the async call so it is seamless for the end user?

Thank's for your help

Comment: Other than going for a really, really bad practice where you introduce a busy loop, you must embrace the async nature and create a new async API.

Comment: The only way to make async sync again is to stop execution until it resolves, using a `while(true)` or something

Comment: If you do not want to introduce an async API, then you can not do asynchronous things; like using webservices. And I don't consider stalling the main thread an option.

Comment: Let me explain it like this: You want to change your supplier from someone local to somone overseas; because reasons. But now, shipping/delivery takes 3 weeks. But you also want to hide this fact away from your customers, so when they order something from you, you want this 3 weeks to instantly dissappear and the product to materialize in your hands so you can still serve your customers immediately, without them waiting. Async programming deals with the problem of time, the time it takes to do something. There is no shortcut in that.

Comment: Great analogy @Thomas.

Comment: @thomas I understand yor analogy, but If I follow it I would say that I did not commit on any shipping delay. And when your provider changes from local shipping to overseas, I may not be aware. The only change I'd do to the API is to mention an exception on timeout

Additionally, If you look to other languages, with continuations, the async calls can be seamless. I do not know why javascript would be the same

Comment: *"I would say that I did not commit on any shipping delay"* doing something asynchronous is the very equivalent of the shipping delay. You know that the response will eventually return, but it ain't here yet. *"And when your provider changes from local shipping to overseas, I may not be aware"* If you can manage your async operations in a way that they are finished when someone requests the result from your API; good for you. *"If you look to other languages, with continuations, the async calls can be seamless"* that's `async/await` in JS.